# Animate.CSS with a child theme

Tags: css, theme-twenty-twelve

I am trying to implement animate.css with my Twenty Twelve child theme. I read [this post](http://wpmu.org/wordpress-animation/) about trying to implement it (option 1), but it is not working. The only thing I am doing differently is that I have a child theme. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** Milo, you're first answer did not work. This is my code in my child theme's function.php:

```
function paukai_2011_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'animate-css',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'http://shaansingh.me/wp-content/themes/twenty-twelve-child/animate.min.css',
        array(),
        '20120725',
        'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-css' );
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<p class="animated wobble">This is dummy text</p>
```

No luck unfortunately.

Comment: Define "not working" ? Do you see stylesheet properly appearing in page source? What is (not) happening?

Comment: The animation is not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the page you linked uses [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri), which will only give you the parent theme URI. If you want to target something in a child theme, you have to swap that for [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), which will give you the child theme URI, in the event a child theme is being used.

Comment: I was linking to the .css file in the parent theme (I had put it there), but I will try this.

Comment: See my original post for the response to your answer.

Comment: you're prepending `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` to a full path, it should just be `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/animate.min.css'` if it's in the root of your child theme directory.